# Getting output in browser using @RequestMappping instead of console

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a java class which will execute a batch file and will return a boolean (true or false) based on whether the command in the batch file has been executed correctly or incorrectly. Right now, i get the boolean on the console of eclipse.

What i want is, i want to create a controller with @RequestMapping so that when i run my application with lets say URL `localhost:8080/runbatchfile`, i should get true/false (in JSON format, meaning either {true} or {false}) on the browser.

This is my **Batchfile.java class** (I am unsure what to return at the getIsSuccessful method. I am really confused.)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BatchFile {
@Test
public void contextLoads() {

    String filePath = "C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/test.bat";
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        boolean isSuccessful = true;

        if (exitVal == 0)

        {
            isSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            isSuccessful = false;
        }

        System.out.println(isSuccessful);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private final boolean isSuccessful ;

public BatchFile(boolean isSuccessful ) {
    this.isSuccessful = isSuccessful ;
}

public boolean getIsSuccessful () {
    return; //what do i have to return here     
  }
}
```

I am also not sure on how to complete my controller class. Here is whatever i have done so far in **BatchFileController.java class**

```
private static final String template="%s";
private static getIsSuccessful 

@RequestMapping("/runBatchFille")
@ResponseBody
public BatchFile batchFile(@RequestParam(value="result") boolean result{
return new BatchFile(String.format(template, result)
  }
}
```

I am new to this and i have tried my best. Someone please help me thank you so much.

Comment: You need to use `@ResponseBody` along with `@RequestMapping` to get `JSON` output.

Comment: Hi, i added it.

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-framework-restcontroller-vs-controller)

Comment: Thank u for sharing that link with me. I have seen that and i have done a similar java project before. However, right now i am confused about the Batchfile.java class as this time i am working with batch files, directories and all and not just simple strings.

Comment: I am also not sure on how to link this class with my controller class